# Can using decorators extract data from parameter passed to function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using webapp2 framework for handling requests from clients. From every header I need to extract some info and use later in response (always same key in header). Problem is that I need to do this for lot off handlers and I want to avoid to repeat same code ( I can write function which from self => self is in get function passed as parameter read and return data), can I do this on elegant way using decorators ?

```
class SomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        # here from self like self.request.headers.get('X-appengine-country') get country info I can extract country and do this for every handler
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def extract_country(f):
  def wrapper(self):
    print self.request.headers.get('X-appengine-country')
    return f(self)
  return wrapper

class SomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @extract_country
    def get(self):
        pass
```

If you want to do it for all methods automatically, then use a metaclass.